# To sum values of object array in TS/JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to calculate total time, but I get string as a result

The code :

```
getCompletedWork(){

    var total:number = 0
    this.state.items.forEach(item => {
        total += item.hours + (item.mins/60)
        console.log("total is : ", total)
    });
    
    return total
}
```

Console output is following

[image]

`item.hours` and `item.mins` are number type fields, but they act as they string :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: it looks like adding strings. you need to convert to number in advance.

Comment: _item.hours and item.mins are number type fields_ - No. It doesn't look like numbers.

Comment: Also `var total:number` is not valid syntax. [edit: nvm]

Comment: @Christian It's typescript :)

Comment: @husnu Try `console.log(typeof item.hours)` and `console.log(typeof item.mins)`

Comment: @NikitaMadeev Oops, missed that, thank you for clarifying :~)

Comment: I use `Item` interface, hours and mins are marked as number in it. @NikitaMadeev you are right cosole output says the are string, but how could it be possible

Comment: Try to add the return type explicitly `getCompleteWork(): number` and also show `typeof` of the operands of the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that a number is interpreted as a number in JavaScript, use the `parseFloat(object)` method when printing the total and the `Number(object)` method when retrieving them into the method, like so;

```
getCompletedWork(){

    var total:number = 0
    this.state.items.forEach(item => {
        total += Number(item.hours) + (Number(item.mins)/60)
        console.log("total is : ", parseFloat(total))
    });

return total
}
```

This will explicitly ensure that the numbers are treated as numbers and not text strings.